# How to find path to class/interface in TS/JS/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to find path to the file from which the class/interface is exported.
Let's say i have a file builder.ts inside ./src folder
with following content:

```
export class Builder {}
```

And i have index.ts in current directory, with following content:

```
import { Builder } from "./src/builder";
```

Later, i might need to know the path to the file, from which Builder class was imported, so i want to have some kind of function, that would take a class/interface/ and return the path to the file where the entity is defined.
So i could write something like this in the index.ts file

```
const path = getPath(Builder)
```

And path variable should equal to "./src/builder".
Is it possible to have this kind of function?

Comment: You already have the path? put the string into a variable

Comment: Hi. I need to have that done automatically.

Comment: Please share a more accurate [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I shared more detailed example.

Comment: Really, your best bet is to create sub-types and follow OOP principles. TypeScript can pick up the type and branch the logic for you.

Comment: Why would you do that? I.e. what is the use-case?

Comment: If you're using ESM you could use the `import.meta.url` value.

Comment: @TmTron I need to get all the keys of the provided typescript interface as a js array. ts-morph can do that, but it needs to know the path to the file, and i don't want to specify that every time.